# "At" / "In" exclusive shop

Tags: prepositions

> She bought her wedding dress **in/at** an exclusive shop on Fifth Avenue.

I think both of them can be used, but my textbook says 'in' is right.

All I know about the difference is 'in' is used when to emphasize what people do in a building or something, but 'at' is used when to emphasize the location itself.

Anyway, is it not possible to use 'at' in this sentence?

Comment: I'd tend to agree. In fact, personally, speaking AmE, I'd probably lean toward **at**. If I'd bought something in a country, I'd say *I bought it **in** Spain.* but if someone asked me, "Where did you get that necklace?", I'd say *I bought it **at** my favorite shop/Angies/a shop downtown.*"

Comment: Either *at* or *in* is fine. Just depends on whether you want to stress whether she was *at* or "*inside*" the shop when she bought the dress.

Comment: I think you are right and your textbook is wrong. That said, are you sure your textbook says that _at_ is wrong? Or does it merely say that _in_ is **better**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At** is a perfectly fine preposition for that sentence, and, indeed, seems more idiomatic to me than **in**. (North-East USA native speaker.)